# Add cell values to Outlook email from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to add certain cell values from a row in Excel to an email in Outlook.

```vb
Sub Email_Record()
'
' Email_Record Macro
' Email Records
'
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

olMail.To = "example@email.com"
olMail.Subject = "Subject"
olMail.Body = "Hello," & vbTab & _
  "I could put text in here all day, but I can't get the cell values in here" & _
  vbTab & "Thank you."
olMail.Display

End Sub
```

From row 2 want to add column a, b, and g

Sample Spreadsheet

[image]

Comment: So what is the problem? Are you saying you want formatted text (use HTMLBody property then) or you don't know how to get the data from Excel? But then it is really an Excel question.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get the excel data to populate in the body of the email.  So when the macro is ran it creates an email with the text and the cells from the selected row in the body of the email.

Comment: Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a well formed HTML string and then assign it to the `HTMLBody` property.

But the simplest solution is to copy a range and paste it in the email message by using the Word object model.

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.
3. [Word editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) - the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The `WordEditor` property of the `Inspector` class returns an instance of the `Document` class from the Word object model which you can use to set up the message body.
   You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx).